# Hangfire disposes of autofac dependencies which are defined as SingleInstance

Tags: c#, .net, autofac, idisposable, hangfire

Using hangfire 1.3.4 with hangfire.autofac 1.0.0 in an ASP.NET application.
I have the following scenario:

```
 class MyType : IDisposable 
 {
      public void Start()
      {
          RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("background-update", () => ProcessData(), Cron.Daily());
          RecurringJob.Trigger("background-update"); 
      }

     public void ProcessData(){...}

     public void Dispose(){...} 
 }
 ...
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
 builder.RegisterType<MyType>().SingleInstance();
 var cont = builder.Build();
 app.UseHangfire(config =>
        {
            var options = new SqlServerStorageOptions();
            config.UseAutofacActivator(cont);
            config.UseSqlServerStorage("MyServer", options);
            config.UseServer();
        });

...
var c = cont.Resolve<MyType>();
c.Start();
```

What I see is that Autofac executes the recurrent job as requested but then disposes of instance of MyType, which obviously causes failures on subsequent calls for it, since it's defined as a singleton, and should be disposed of by Autofac upon shutdown.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Here's the callstack:

> MyDll.dll!MyType.Dispose() Line 316 C#
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Common.Job.Dispose(object instance)  Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Common.Job.Perform(Hangfire.JobActivator activator, Hangfire.IJobCancellationToken cancellationToken)    Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.JobPerformanceProcess.PerformJobWithFilters.AnonymousMethod__6()  Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.JobPerformanceProcess.InvokePerformFilter(Hangfire.Server.IServerFilter filter, Hangfire.Server.PerformingContext preContext, System.Func continuation) Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.JobPerformanceProcess.PerformJobWithFilters.AnonymousMethod__8()  Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.JobPerformanceProcess.InvokePerformFilter(Hangfire.Server.IServerFilter filter, Hangfire.Server.PerformingContext preContext, System.Func continuation) Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.JobPerformanceProcess.PerformJobWithFilters.AnonymousMethod__8()  Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.JobPerformanceProcess.PerformJobWithFilters(Hangfire.Server.PerformContext context, Hangfire.Server.IJobPerformer performer, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable filters)   Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.JobPerformanceProcess.Run(Hangfire.Server.PerformContext context, Hangfire.Server.IJobPerformer performer)    Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.Worker.ProcessJob(string jobId, Hangfire.Storage.IStorageConnection connection, Hangfire.Server.IJobPerformanceProcess process, System.Threading.CancellationToken shutdownToken) Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.Worker.Execute(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.AutomaticRetryServerComponentWrapper.ExecuteWithAutomaticRetry(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.AutomaticRetryServerComponentWrapper.Execute(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)    Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.ServerSupervisor.ExecuteComponent()   Unknown
>       Hangfire.Core.dll!Hangfire.Server.ServerSupervisor.RunComponent()   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)    Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()    Unknown
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

Comment: Could you put a breakpoint on the `dispose` method and look at the call stack to identify why this type is disposed ? If you need help, edit your question and include the call stack.

Comment: Posted the callstack

Comment: If we look at the source of *HangFire*, we can see that it manages the lifetime of the object and doesn't let *Autofac* do. look at the line 97 of [Job.cs](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/Common/Job.cs). Why do you need a Singleton ?

Comment: The workaround indeed was not to use a singleton. But I think this points to a bug in Hangfire-Autofac (and probably other DI frameworks) integration. If the object is not instantiated by Hangfire, but by the DI container, I believe it should not Dispose of it, but let the container do it's job.

Comment: I don't know Hangfire but after looking at the source code I agree with you that it looks like a design bug in *Hangfire* :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in latest (beta) releases of hangfire, see https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/329 for details.